# Python - Calculate angle from object1(as x and y) to object2(as x and y)

Tags: python

[image]
I need exemple in Python, how to calc function like:

```
AngleFromObject1ToObject2InDegrees(object1, object2) # return float from 0.0 to 359.00 like 0-360 degrees, 360 = 0
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @ImLearning. What did you already try? Do you have a piece of code You should read "[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" in order to improve your question.

Comment: @ndclt Well, I don't know how to calculate it. I have x and y of object 1 and object 2. I need to calculate the rotation angle of object 1, relative to object 2. Eg, to be able to rotate object 1, towards object 2.

Comment: Something like rotation of the tank turret which I am aiming at the object 2 in degrees. I don't have code, cuz I don't have idea how to calc it fast

Comment: You can use the polar coordinate system. https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/polar-coordinates#:~:text=To%20convert%20from%20Cartesian%20coordinates,1(yx))%20. Given 2 points (x,y), you can translate them both to where object 1 is at (0, 0) and then convert to polar coordinates, which will give an angle and the distance between the two.

Comment: @Shmack I don't know much about math. In another programming language, as I was doing, there was a ready-made function for that. I wonder if there is any ready solution or if someone could translate this formula into Python code for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic use case for the `math.atan2` function:

```
from math import atan2, degrees

def AngleFromObject1ToObject2InDegrees(object1, object2):
    return degrees(atan2(object2.y - object1.y, object2.x - object1.x))
```

Note that this uses the mathematical convention of angles that start at zero along the positive x-axis (to the right), and increase counter-clockwise. If you want `0` to be up and for them to increase clockwise (like the bearings on a magnetic compass's dial), you can swap the arguments to `atan2`. You also might consider keeping your angle in radians, it's a lot more convenient that way (since other trigonometric functions expect radians).

Comment: It's genius and simple answer. For now, I think I understood. Thank You very much

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to translate one of the points to the origin, offset the other point by the same distance we offset the point moved to the origin, then convert the second point (not the origin point) to polar coordinates. What this returns is a distance between the origin and the point, as well as, the angle.

```
import math
# where object1 and object2 are tuples of x, y pairs
def AngleFromObject1ToObject2InDegrees(object1, object2):
    translate_to_origin = (object1[0] - 0, object1[1] - 0)
    new_points = (object2[0] - translate_to_origin[0], object2[1] - translate_to_origin[1])
    return (math.sqrt(new_points[0] ** 2 + new_points[1] ** 2), math.degrees(math.atan(new_points[1] / new_points[0])))

print(AngleFromObject1ToObject2InDegrees((1,1),(5,5)))
print(AngleFromObject1ToObject2InDegrees((5,5),(1,1)))
```

As a "one liner":

```
import math
# where object1 and object2 are tuples of x, y pairs
def AngleFromObject1ToObject2InDegrees(object1, object2):
    return (math.sqrt((object2[0] - object1[0]) ** 2 + (object2[1] - object1[1]) ** 2), math.degrees(math.atan((object2[1] - object1[1]) / (object2[0] - object1[0]))))

print(AngleFromObject1ToObject2InDegrees((1,1),(5,5)))
print(AngleFromObject1ToObject2InDegrees((5,5),(1,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could done by using simple trigonometry, first you calculate the horizontal distance between object1 and object2 i.e `x_2 - x_1` and then calculate the vertical distance b/w object1 and object2 i.e `y_2 - y_1`. The horizontal distance is our base and the vertical distance is our perpendicular.
`perpendicular/base = tan(θ)` now take inverse
`atan(perpendicular/base) = θ`

A way of implementing this in python will be easy you can use `math.atan` to achieve your purpose something like
`math.atan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))`

Comment: I don't know much about math. In another programming language, as I was doing, there was a ready-made function for that. I wonder if there is any ready solution or if someone could translate this formula into Python code for me :/